# pundit for rails trouble configuring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pundit

I have built a web app using rails 4.2.4, devise and a pins scaffolding where users can CRUD a pin.

I am about to medicate myself trying to get pundit working so that only the Admin can CRUD a pin, all users signed in or guests can only view and cannot create, update or destroy.

I get a litany of errors like this> [image]

Facts:

I have 2 models pin.rb and user.rb

I have a pins_controller.rb

I done a migration add_admin_to_users.rb (do i need further intervention in the console to set something up for admin besides this)

Can I get help with the syntax and my failed approach

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :pin

  def initialize(user, pin)
    raise Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, "must be logged in" unless user
    @user = user
    @pin = pin
  end

  def index?
    true
  end

  def show?
    scope.where(:id => record.id).exists?
  end

  def create?
    user.admin? 
  end

  def new?
    user.admin? 
  end

  def update?
    user.admin? 
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    user.admin? 
  end

  def scope
    Pundit.policy_scope!(user, record.class)
  end

  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      scope
    end
  end
end
```

> Blockquote

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    if params[:search].present? && !params[:search].nil?
      @pins = Pin.where("description LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
    else
      @pins = Pin.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
    end
  end


  def show

  end


  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.build
  end


  def edit
  end


  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
    if @pin.save
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end


  def update
    if @pin.update(pin_params)
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @pin.destroy
    redirect_to pins_url
  end


private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find_by(id: params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this pin" if @pin.nil?
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image)
    end
end
```

> Blockquote

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 include Pundit
 rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception
 before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

 protected

 def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name
 end

 private

 def user_not_authorized
   flash[:warning] = "You are not authorized to perform this action."
   redirect_to(request.referrer || root_path)
 end
end
```

Comment: do you have a `PinPolicy` class? :)

Comment: Is that what I need in this code

Comment: see my answer please

Comment: let me try this out now, thank you. will revert shortly, is their any else retarded in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors occur most likely simply do to the fact, that, well, as the exception states, there is no `PinPolicy` class. Apart from general `ApplicationPolicy` you should also define the policy for each resource (which inherits from main `ApplicationPolicy`).

Add it under `/policies` directory:

```
class PinPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      return scope if user.admin?
      fail 'scope is not defined'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: how should i code this in the application-policy ,  below the def initializer, or what. Do I need to delete any code in my policy above

Comment: @ChrisDormani Create new file in `app/policies` called `pin_policy.rb` and put the code I showed there

Comment: appreciate your time, will try this momentarily

Comment: and in terms of doing the authorisation on the pin for each of the resource (Create, Update etc), would that be called as authorize.pin or @pin.authorize

Comment: @ChrisDormani did it work? If yes, consider accepting (checkmark on the left of the answer), and optionally upvoting the answer

Comment: returning to the office in 15 minutes, will deploy and up vote

Comment: Right, I have created a new file as you advocated. And bumped that code in. Beneath that do I need to def create?
    user.admin? 
  end

Comment: If you look at my application policy above, their is index, show, create new, update. Do I need to copy these into the pin_policy.rb

Comment: @ChrisDormani no, since every method defined in `ApplicationPolicy` is inherited by PinPolicy, so it already has this `create?` method, since it is defined in `ApplicationPolicy`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102484/discussion-between-chris-dormani-and-andrey-deineko).